# Why does find_next_sibling in bs4 work on one line of code but not another, very similar, line of code?

Tags: python-3.x, object, beautifulsoup

I'm writing a simple web scraper to get data from the Texas Commission on Environmental Quality (TCEQ) website. The info I need is inside 'td' tags. I'm scraping the appropriate 'td' by referencing the preceding 'th', which all have the same text used to ID. I'm using find_next_sibling to scrape the data into a variable.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www2.tceq.texas.gov/oce/eer/index.cfm?fuseaction=main.getDetails&target=323191"

r = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

###This one works
report = soup.find("th", text="Incident Tracking Number:").find_next_sibling("td").text

###This one doesn't
owner = soup.find("th", text="Name of Owner or Operator:").find_next_sibling("td").text
```

I'm getting this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next_sibling'. This code has several lines like the two above, and, like them, some of them work and some of them don't. I've looked into the HTML to see if there's another tag, but I'm not seeing it if it's there. Please and thank you for any help!

Comment: Are you really sure that the `soup.find` is actually finding a tag? If not,  then that would explain why it throws the error.

Comment: It's finding it in the first variable and some others I had written. The html is set up the exact same way for the second one, with the 'td' containing the text I need, while it's preceded by the 'th' with the identifier. Not sure why it finds it in one and not the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `text` parameter, you should make sure you provide the text exactly. In your case, there's a space at the end.

```
soup.find('th', text='Name of Owner or Operator: ').find_next_sibling('td').text
```

This prints:

```
\n      \n      \n      \n        \n        PHILLIPS 66 COMPANY\n        \n      \n
```

Comment: This worked...thanks! I knew it would be something simple. Those random spaces make a huge difference. Good reminder to comb over every little thing. Thanks again!